# BlackBerry Bitmap listener

Tags: blackberry, listener, paint

I have a code similar to the one below, painting over the mapfields this mIcon several times. 
How can I add a click listener to this bitmap ? I am using bb 5.0

```
public Bitmap mIcon;
mIcon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("pcture1.png");

protected void paint(Graphics g) {


 super.paint(g);
        mDest = new XYRect(....);
        g.drawBitmap(mDest, mIcon, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override BitmapField and modify the isFocusable(), navigationClick(), keyChar(), and trackwheelClick() methods.

```
public class ImageButtonField extends BitmapField
{

   public ImageButtonField(Bitmap image)
   {
      super(image);
   }

   public boolean isFocusable() 
   {
      return true;
   }

   protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
   {
     fieldChangeNotify(0);
     return true;
   }

   protected boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time)
   {
     fieldChangeNotify(0);
     return true;
   }

   protected boolean keyChar(char character, int status, int time)
   {
      if(Characters.ENTER == character || Characters.SPACE == character)
      {
         fieldChangeNotify(0);
         return true;
      }
      return super.keyChar(character, status, time);
   }

}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. How can I add this to a MapField? Should the icons be added dynamically depending on the center of the map associated to the screen ?

Comment: Hello Jonathan, how can you draw a bitmap field using Graphics ? Is the navigation click also applyable for tap event ?